# send an array in javascript to phpscript

Tags: jquery

In my page I need to send an array in javascript to Phpscript. My code doesn't return a value and does not give an error. How can I do that?

```
arr[0]='one';
arr[1]='two';
arr[2]='three';
arr[3]='four';

$.post(
       'sort2.php', 
       {data:arr}, 
       function(result) {
                         alert(result[0]);                  
       },
       'json' 
);
```

In sort2.php

```
$data=$_GET["arr"];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Are you posting from client and looking for sent data in `$_GET` array?

Comment: yes, I want to get values of arr array in phpscript.

Comment: You are posting you should use `$_POST` array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You got `$_GET` and `$_POST` mixed up in the PHP script.
2. It should be `$_POST['data']`, not `$_POST['arr']` (the `arr` array is passed under the key name `data` in your JavaScript code: `{data:arr}`.)

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
$data=$_POST["arr"];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using POST method to send data. You should read the `$_POST` array